# Mobile broadband Server backup

Tags: windows, networking, redundancy, ups

We have a windows server. It is attached to a UPS. The internet connection is not plugged into the UPS. If the power goes down in the building the UPS kicks in and emails out saying that the UPS is working. There is no internet connection as the modem has gone down. Is it possible to have a 3g data card in the server so the email can send out? Can the server use a wired connection when available and the 3g connection when the wired connection is not there?

Comment: What about plugging the modem into the UPS, too?

Answer (score 2):

You could install a USB air card in the server (provided you find one that supports a server operating system). Once it's all setup, configure the network settings to prefer the wired connection over the wireless one (Here's the instructions for doing this with Windows XP. The process is pretty much the same for all Windows OSes http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894564). Make sure your firewall is configured correctly. Those air cards usually stick you directly on the internet with no NAT or firewall in between.

Comment: it also depends on how your outgoing email is routed, using a 3g data card will assign a random external IP from the provider. If you use a outgoing mail feed it may reject email whilst using teh 3g card. It may also be worth looking into a load balancing router (Draytek are very good for this and dont break the bank)